# How can I see full commit messages in the (GIT) commit list in VSTS?

Tags: azure-devops

We're using a GIT repository in VSTS.

The VSTS website has a list of all commits, but the "Message" column only shows the first line of each commit message.

You can see the full message if you hover over the displayed message text, but that is not a good way to read through the log.

Is there a way to have that list show the full message text?

Comment: No. There isn't. Though you may be able to write an extension for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The website has not this feature out-of-the-box, but I believe you could write an extension to achieve this, or use the REST API to get the commits to Excel.

Comment: The place to vote for this feature is the [VS community idea 389314](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/389314/add-option-to-see-full-commit-message-in-pull-requ.html)

Answer (score 2):

No, there isn’t way to show full commit message directly in commit list web UI.

You can build an application or VSTS extension (e.g. hub) to get the commit message through [Get a Commit REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/git/commits/get). (Note: [Get List Commits REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/git/commits/get%20commits) won’t include whole commit message)

[Add a hub extension.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/extend/develop/add-hub?view=vsts)